# Is the dataset that underpins the Windows Character Map utility accessible somewhere on the system?

Tags: windows, fonts, unicode, character-map

The Windows *Character Map* utility displays the glyphs available in the chosen font, along with the Unicode codepoint and a name for a selected character. Is the dataset that underpins this utility read-accessible on the system somewhere?

Comment: Yes, but only by writing some code ...

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Even its location would be of help. Not asking for the code, of course.

Comment: Windows generates the CharMap from the fonts data using the Windows API so the information is located in the fonts.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks.